Time difference in Seconds between two Timestamp columns in Pandas
I need to compute and add the timestamp difference between two columns in seconds in the given dataframe
df = 

A                                     B          
Wed Jul 31 07:09:48 EDT 2024    Wed Jul 31 07:04:35 EDT 2024

Wed Jul 31 07:26:31 EDT 2024    Wed Jul 31 07:21:04 EDT 2024    


Need to add column C with timestamp difference of A and B in seconds
A                                     B                               C
Wed Jul 31 07:09:48 EDT 2024    Wed Jul 31 07:04:35 EDT 2024         

Wed Jul 31 07:26:31 EDT 2024    Wed Jul 31 07:21:04 EDT 2024

Any suggestions on how to compute this ?

Can you please upload your code so far? best guess that i have is using something along the lines of df['C'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).astype('timedelta64[s]')

I assume you may just use the inner pandas .dt.total_seconds() method as shown below. Here you may consider two ways of doing it:

first is update your dataframe with standard pandas datetime format and get the following result

df = df.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['C'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).dt.total_seconds()

and the output will be
    A                    B                    C
0   2024-07-31 07:09:48  2024-07-31 07:04:35  313.0
1   2024-07-31 07:26:31  2024-07-31 07:21:04  327.0


The other way to do this is to create a copy of your dataframe in order to save the data type and format of your A, B columns, and then you can just drop the copy from your machine memory with del, so the code will be mostly similar:

df_copy = df.copy().astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['C'] = (df_copy['A'] - df_copy['B']).dt.total_seconds()
del df_copy

the output:
    A                             B                             C
0   Wed Jul 31 07:09:48 EDT 2024  Wed Jul 31 07:04:35 EDT 2024  313.0
1   Wed Jul 31 07:26:31 EDT 2024  Wed Jul 31 07:21:04 EDT 2024  327.0


You can have best of both ways with something like
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].astype('datetime64[ns]').eval('A-B').dt.total_seconds()

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html
Probably this is what you need
